# Multi-Catches Problems

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I copied something from a different class, and yet it gave me an error even though it didn't in the original. Here's the code:

```
package com.dinobuilding;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Window {

public static int screenHeight = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height;
public static int screenWidth = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width;

public static ImageIcon background = new ImageIcon("resources/images/Background.png");

public static ImageObserver observer;

public Window() {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("DinoBuilding");

            try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Window();
}

}
```

I've probably messed something up really trivial, but it will not stop telling me "Multi-catches are not supported at this language level". If you need more information that I probably forgot to mention, just ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have a switch on your command line or IDE that's set to Java version 1.6 or less.  Multicatch requires 1.7 or greater.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multi catch statements are only supported in `Java 7` and  higher versions, make sure that you are not running a version below that.
[Check this out](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/project-general-settings-page.html)  to see how you can change the Project language level in `IDEA`. I am assuming that you have Java 7 or a version higher installed on your system, if you don't then go and get the latest version of Java

Comment: Thank you, but I copied it from the same IDE, so that doesn't make a ton of sense.

Comment: @LordMastodon Well, I've noticed that in IDEA as well. I don't know if there is a way to tell IDEA to use a certain lang version by default

Comment: So you're saying that each project has a different JDK thingy?

Comment: @LordMastodon Normally there is a default, but you can certainly set project specific runtimes & compile levels in any modern IDE.

Comment: @LordMastodon No, it has nothing to do with the JDK, IDEA sometimes select a random language level (at least for me )

Comment: @LordMastodon check the project language level and not the JDK

Comment: What do you mean? I'm kinda new to IntelliJ... How do I find that?

Comment: Right click on the project -> module settings-> Project Language level-> Select Java 7

Answer (score 1):

Multi-catches like `catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex)` are only supported from Java 7 and onwards. I believe your JDK/Java compliter is earlier than JDK1.7.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/catch-multiple.html

Please check that. If possible, upgrade to JDK 1.7. Else use the catch block as following...

```
try {
  // Do something
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
  // Do something
} catch(InstantiationException ex) {
 // Do something
} catch(IllegalAccessException ex) {
 // Do something
} catch(UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
 // Do something
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: But it did not give me any errors in the original project, which was done in the same IDE.